# Is there any valuable information in the Holonet on TDS?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I typically amuse myself by reading the status updates on Holonet.  They tell you that levels are closed, people like their new jobs, etc.  But, is there any strategic information there?  I expect that the answer is no, but I am including this question to help complete the knowledge base on the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen strategic info there.  There are some inside / pop culture jokes.
I am at 89 bitizens 62 floors.  I don't even check it unless I am completely bored.